# whats the difference between '!=' and '<>' in mysql

Tags: mysql

whats the difference between `!=` and `<>` in mysql.
which symbol is good to user in sql query for not equal condition.can someone tell me whats the pros and cons of using the not equal symbol in mysql.

Answer (score 84):

`!=` requires 3 keystrokes (Shift, !, =), and `<>` requires 3 keystrokes (Shift, <, >).  However a touch typist has to switch hands to hit that `=`.

You should definitely use `<>` over `!=`.  You'll save at least 10 milliseconds of typing for each use.

Comment: I do not agree. You have to perform the same actions for both (more or less): `Shift, !, release Shift, =` and `Shift, <, >, release Shift`. Also because for `<>` you have to hold the `Shift` twice longer you will suffer more stress in your fingers. Also the buttons are closer to each other for `<>` and that contributes as well to the stress in the articulations. **TL;DR** `<>` is bad for your long term health. ISO should really take this into consideration and update the standard!

Comment: Seriously now, it's harder to type `<>` than `!=`. Try it.

Comment: @Alin Purcaru: I wrote this answer with my tongue planted in my cheek, but I have to disagree.  For a touch typist, `<>` is faster to type than `!=`.

Comment: it depends on the keyboard layout, but for me there is 3 keystorek on both, don't know what keyboard layout alin have, or if he switched them by mistake, "shift + ( 1, 0 )" gives me "!=", and "<, shift + <" gives med "<>"

Comment: @Michael Martin-Smucker: I made a mistake in the original answer.  Changed.

Comment: @Puggan Se I have the US qwerty layout, and I would guess that is the most common one. ... Maybe we should stop here. We're really going off topic :).

Comment: @Alin Purcaru: Yes, we're going way off topic.  However, some questions deserve the satirical treatment.

Comment: But `!=` makes more sense. Simply read the letters out loud and you'll understand the meaning `not, equal` compared to reading `less than, greater than`.

Comment: Okay now consider a keyboard other than us-int :P

Comment: With an AZERTY keyboard != doesn't require the use of the shift key while <> does (but switching between QUERTY and AZERTY will result in a massive number of typing errors!)

Answer (score 30):

There is absolutely [no difference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_not-equal) in MySQL, but the `<>` is the variant present in the SQL ISO standard.

*If you're interested in trivia I can tell you that Oracle also has `^=` apart from those two.*

Answer (score 7):

There is no difference.  According to SQL.org, the != operator is converted to be <> by the compiler/interpreter during execution so in essence it is just an alias.

http://www.sql.org/sql-database/postgresql/manual/functions-comparison.html

Comment: You did see that that is the documentation for PostgreSQL, right?

Comment: yes but is really based on the standard so most sql implementations will probably implement in similar manner.  although to be absolutely sure i suppose I could dig into the code of the MYSQL since it is open source ish.