# What are differences between MySQL != and <>

Tags: mysql, sql, database, logic, operators

I want to know why MySQL has `<>` and `!=`

**Using `<>`**:

```
SELECT *
FROM `products`
WHERE `deleted` <> 0
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

(I exacted this query for 5 times and the average execute time for 5 times is *0.00018 sec*)

---

**Using `!=`**:

```
SELECT *
FROM `products`
WHERE `deleted` != 0
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

(And I also exacted this query for 5 times and the average execute time for 5 times is *0.00016 sec*)

As I got; It seems that `!=` is faster than `<>`, but what is the reason to have two unequal operators?

what are differences between these two operators?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are the same and equivalent to each other.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_not-equal

And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7040305/whats-the-difference-between-and-in-mysql/7040456) this question asked before, and there are some answers there!